# Atom/Electron/Web applications and accessibility APIs (macOS and Windows)

Tags: objective-c, macos, electron, accessibility

I'm looking into utilizing accessibility APIs provided by macOS and Windows for an application.

The [AX stuff for macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accessibility?language=objc) works fine, I can get all the elements of a native Cocoa application.

The [Windows APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-uiautomationoverview) is also promising.

However, apps built with frameworks like Electron and such, which incorporate a "web view" are not accessible through the native APIs. They just appear as a black box. This is also the case using the Accessibility Inspector utility for macOS.

I'm not convinced this is a dead end though, because the macOS VoiceOver utility can dig into the web elements and inspect them. Are there separate APIs I need to use to get access to the web elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, just to answer my own question, the key is to set the `AXManualAccessibility` to true before querying the app's accessibility elements.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/accessibility#macos

Comment: Much thanks for this! I love that you answered your own question and the solution was helpful to me as well.

Comment: I am also providing an updated link to the electron documentation you referred to: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/accessibility

Comment: Any example of a minimal Electron program that queries other runnings apps using UIA (Microsoft UI Automation) for example?

Answer (score -1):

Hey any chance I can get some help with this?
I have the project that is built on Electron, and we are trying to implement the button that has the functionality turn on the screen reader, but kinda stuck :/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Sean. I would post some code and share what you have tried so far. People will be more likely to answer if they don't have to ask to see your code or what you have already tried.

Comment: I think you'll have better luck posting your own question with some more relevant info and code examples.