# How to get focused element's cursor position using accessibility API in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility

I'm working on a mac app that uses Accessibility APIs to get the cursor position from the focused element (Focused element can be from any app) and shows a window near the cursor position.

I checked the window positioning in native apps like XCode, Notes, and Messages and tried on web apps as well everything is working fine.

I checked the same on the slack desktop app where I'm facing an issue. Which is I'm getting the **XOrigin** always as 0 and **YOrigin** as 982 (That is equal to my screen's size: NSScreen.main?.frame.height). Seems it is breaking on **electron apps**. What am I missing here? Do we need to account for anything else to handle electron apps?

Attaching my code for reference.

```
  extension AXUIElement {
      func getCursorRect() -> CGRect? {
        guard let cursorPosition = cursorPosition else {return nil}
        var cfRange: CFRange = .init(location: cursorPosition, length: 1)
        let axval: AXValue? = AXValueCreate(.cfRange, &cfRange)
        var bounds: CFTypeRef?
        guard let axval = axval else {return nil}
        AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue(self, kAXBoundsForRangeParameterizedAttribute as CFString, axval, &bounds)
        var cursorRect: CGRect = .zero
        guard let bounds = bounds else {return nil}
        AXValueGetValue(bounds as! AXValue, .cgRect, &cursorRect)
        return cursorRect
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is "cursor position" the position of the mouse cursor or the insertion point? Is the value of `cursorPosition` correct? Do the electron apps support accessibility, have you tried the Accessibility Inspector?

Comment: I looking to get the position of an insertion point. I'm able to get the mouse pointer position using `NSEvent.locationInWindow` but that's not needed for my case. 
I don't know how to find an application do support accessibility, I'm not aware of that part.

Comment: Have you tried the Accessibility Inspector, a Xcode Developer Tool?

Comment: Maybe related: [Atom/Electron/Web applications and accessibility APIs (macOS and Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66223599/atom-electron-web-applications-and-accessibility-apis-macos-and-windows)

Comment: @ArulMuruganSivapoosam Have you ever found a solution for that? Because I have the exact same problem...

Comment: @codingFriend1 No I couldn't find a way to get an exact position. So I added a fallback implementation using **kAXPositionAttribute** attribute, which will give an origin of a focused element. It's working for me in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `AXSeletedTextRange` attribute.
Offcourse if no text selected the range length will be 0, but location should be exact keyboard cursor position in line.
`AXInsertionPointLineNumber` will give you line number.
By this keyboard cursor position, I think is possible to calculate cursor coordinates.